# rounding off to 2 decimal place in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm new to programming. Today, I have a question regarding jQuery. Currently, I am doing a code whereby if i were to type something in a text box, the value will be generated without refreshing somewhere on the same webpage. The code is currently working, however after I add in the round function, the code does not seem to run anymore. Will appreciate if you are keen to help. Thanks!

```
 $( "#noofpax1" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    $( "#pax1" ).text( round ((value * 13.21) ,2 ));
  })
  .keyup();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `.toFixed()` at this context,

```
$("#pax1").text((value * 13.21).toFixed(2));
```

Answer (score 0):

use `toFixed(2)`  `inside text()`

dont use round().

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JjZ72/)

Reason ur code didnt work : Round a number to the nearest integer.It doesnt accept second parameter.

For details about ur question
[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried using toFixed(2) but it does not work. 
$( "#noofpax1" )
  .keyup(function() {
    var value = $( this ).val();
    $( "#pax1" ).text( value * 13.21 ).toFixed(2);
  })
  .keyup();

Am I doing it correctly?
@jQueryAngryBird

Comment: Check fiddle i posteed

Comment: @sing , i had to say inside text(). Did u check jsFiddle?